# How to delete an item from RecyclerAdapter Android application

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm encountering an issue in my Android app where duplicate chatroom entries are appearing in the RecyclerView, despite efforts to remove chatrooms associated with deleted user accounts. Initially, I implemented logic to query Firestore for chatroom data and successfully removed chatrooms linked to deleted accounts from the dataset. However, I noticed that chat entries with active user accounts are now being duplicated in the RecyclerView. This unexpected behavior is perplexing, as I expected that only valid chatrooms, corresponding to active user accounts, would be displayed in the RecyclerView after removing chatrooms associated with deleted accounts. I've thoroughly reviewed my code, ensuring that the dataset is updated correctly and that chatrooms are properly filtered based on user account status. Despite these efforts, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class RecentChatRecyclerAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ChatroomModel, RecentChatRecyclerAdapter.ChatroomModelViewHolder> {
    private final String TAG = "OUTPUT";
    Context context;

    public RecentChatRecyclerAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ChatroomModel> options,Context context) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatroomModelViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ChatroomModel model) {
        FirebaseUtil.getOtherUserFromChatroom(model.getUserIds())
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                            boolean lastMessageSentByMe = model.getLastMessageSenderId().equals(FirebaseUtil.currentUserId());

                            UserModel otherUserModel = document.toObject(UserModel.class);
                            if (otherUserModel != null) {
                                FirebaseUtil.getOtherProfilePicStorageRef(otherUserModel.getUserId()).getDownloadUrl()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(t -> {
                                            if(t.isSuccessful()){
                                                Uri uri  = t.getResult();
                                                AndroidUtil.setProfilePic(context,uri,holder.profilePic);
                                            }
                                        });

                                holder.usernameText.setText(otherUserModel.getUsername());
                                if(lastMessageSentByMe)
                                    holder.lastMessageText.setText("You : "+model.getLastMessage());
                                else
                                    holder.lastMessageText.setText(model.getLastMessage());
                                holder.lastMessageTime.setText(FirebaseUtil.timestampToString(model.getLastMessageTimestamp()));

                                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                                    //navigate to chat activity
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
                                    AndroidUtil.passUserModelAsIntent(intent,otherUserModel);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                });
                            } else {
                                // UserModel is null, remove this item from the dataset
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Here1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Document does not exist or is null, remove this item from the dataset
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Here2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //todo: change this line
                            //notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Here3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error getting document: ", task.getException());
                        // Handle the error, such as displaying an error message to the user
                    }
                });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChatroomModelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recent_chat_recycler_row,parent,false);
        return new ChatroomModelViewHolder(view);
    }

    class ChatroomModelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView usernameText;
        TextView lastMessageText;
        TextView lastMessageTime;
        ImageView profilePic;

        public ChatroomModelViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            usernameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_text);
            lastMessageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_message_text);
            lastMessageTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_message_time_text);
            profilePic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_image_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, here are some useful resources ([1](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) & [2](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166)) that might help.